# when creating shards in solr...."shards can be added only to 'implicit' collections"

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We don't need SPLITSHARD.
I have given numShards=1 while creating a collection. We need shard2 for the same collection. we are getting below error while creating shard2 for the same collection.

**Error:shards can be added only to 'implicit' collections**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods of router implementation used by collection. `default` is "compositeId" router.

So if Collection is created with `compositeId` router method, **we cannot create new shard**.
Only possible way is to split the existing shard.

As error indicates shards can be added only to 'implicit' collections

If you create the collection with `implicit` router you can add shards.
you can additionally define a `router.field` parameter to use a field from each document to identify a shard where the document belongs. If the field specified is missing in the document, however, the document will be rejected

[more on document routing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud)

Comment: How can I identify my collections  are "compositeId" or "implicit"

Comment: while creating collection using Collection API there parameter `router.name` is default set to compositeId. you can change it to implicit but it does not automatically route documents to different shards(which is done with compositeId router method).

Comment: check these Collection API parameter https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

Comment: How to "compositeId" to "implicit". If I change to "implicit"  what is the advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: if you create collection using implicit router. you can specifically index each document into specific shard, which need you documents must have a field which is used to map to specific shard while indexing.  `router.field` read about document routing. adv: can create shards, can index into specific shard. disadvan:extra work to direct each document to shard. document without router.field value is rejected/not indexed.

Comment: Kindly share your suggestion on:
How can I use router.field in an existing collection?

Comment: `I have updated compositeId to implicit using zookeeper.  
**Steps:**  
1.Login zookeeper. Go to your collections. 
 2..check the state.json file edit and update compositeId to implicit.  
3..check the CLUSTERSTATUS call [<IP>:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS&wt=json].....  
4..Check the router name.`  


**Note: My question is if I change the compositeId to implicit in production any impact will happen? Please update.**

Comment: Not the better way. I suggest to create new collection with implicit router and reindex all documents with every documents having router.filed so that you can point document to specific shard.  read about document routing. this link might help : http://rutlib2.com/book/4190/p/74

Comment: That's ok... **if I change the compositeId to implicit in production any impact will happen?** Please explain